# Unable to install SimpleITK library

Tags: python, anaconda, simpleitk

I am installing using following command:

```
python -m pip install SimpleITK
```

I got an error using  CMake. The error message is given below:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/ExternalData.cmake:1121 (message): Object MD5=890c808122bd90f398e6bc40ec862102 not found
```

The complete traceback is given as:

```
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ipcv-lab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 589, in setup
        cmkr.make(make_args, env=env)
      File "/home/ipcv-lab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 507, in make
        os.path.abspath(CMAKE_BUILD_DIR())))
    
    An error occurred while building with CMake.
      Command:
        cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
      Source directory:
        /tmp/pip-build-cUCNSY/SimpleITK
      Working directory:
        /tmp/pip-build-cUCNSY/SimpleITK/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-2.7/cmake-build
    Please see CMake's output for more information.
```

I have tried installing with conda as well, but I am getting an error of unavailable channels

Answer (score 0):

It looks like cmake is trying to compile SimpleITK.  Not sure why it needs to do that for a pip install.

You could try downloading the Python wheel for SimpleITK directly and installing the wheel.  Here's where you can download the package:

```
https://pypi.org/project/SimpleITK/#files
```

Also it looks like you're using Python 2.7.  SimpleITK isn't supported on 2.7.  You're going to have to use 3.5 or up.

As far as conda goes, did you use the "-c condo-forge" option to select the proper channel to download SimpleITK?